# python: explain if list:

Tags: python

I have been given a script that converts a multiline sequence to a single line sequence, however I don't understand how it works.

I'm new to python and have never used blocks before.

Here is the code:

```
with open("pandas.fas") as f_input, open("singleline.fas", 'w') as f_output:
    block = [] 
    for line in f_input:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if block:
                f_output.write(''.join(block) + '\n')
                block = []
            f_output.write(line)
        else:
            block.append(line.strip())
    if block:
        f_output.write(''.join(block) + '\n')
```

Please can someone help me understand?

I am especially confused about this segment:

```
            if block:
                f_output.write(''.join(block) + '\n')
                block = []
```

Comment: `block` is just a name, defined in line 2. It's not a special Python thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script collects the non-header lines in the list variable `block`. When it sees a header line, it checks whether `block` contains anything, which means it belongs to the previous header line, and has not been printed yet -- if so, it prints out the pending output as a single line, then clears the list of collected lines and starts over.

A common beginner error with this sort of algorithm is to forget to print the last batch of collected data when the loop ends, but this script nicely takes care of that too.

Notice how `line.strip()` removes any trailing newline from every line which is added to `block`, and so the result of joining those is a single line; the `write` then just adds a single newline at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `block` is a list type variable of python. It is similar to array in C. `block =[]` defines an empty list. 
The condition `if block:` checks whether `block` is empty or not. If `block` is not empty, it joins the content of `block` and writes in the output file.